# How to add north arrow to map using ArcGIS silverlight API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, north-arrow

I think it's a simple question but i don't answer it. I want to add North arrow in my webgis using silverlight API. How can I do it? Is there any sample code to add north arrow using silverlight api ?

Comment: [This Esri discussion](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/12715) seems to imply that it can't really be done automatically, but you can add a graphic image of a north arrow.